# Memory leak when using JDK compiler at runtime

Tags: reflection, classloader, java

I am trying to add a javaeditor to my program to extend the program at run time. It all works fine, except when using the program extensively (I simulated 1000-10000 compiler executions). The memory usage rises and rises, it looks like there is a memory leak.

In my program, the class gets loaded, the constructor gets executed and the class gets unloaded (no remaining instance and the classLoader becomes invalid as I set the pointer to null). I analyzed the process with JConsole, the classes get unloaded when the garbage collector is executed.

I did a heapdum opened it in memory analyzer, the problem seems to be inside of java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader (in a com.sun.tools.javac.util.List Object). Since (com.sun.tools.javac) is part of the JDK and not in the JRE and the SystemToolClassLoader is an FactoryURLClassLoader Object, I would locate the leak somewhere there. The number of loaded classes in the SystemToolClassLoader rises from 1 to 521 when I execute the compiler the first time but stays the same afterwards.

So I have no idea where the leak is , is there a way to reset the SystemToolClassLoader? How could I locate the leak more precisely.

**EDIT: Okay I found out it also occurs in a very very simple example. So it seems to be a part of the compilation, i don't need to load the class or instantiate it:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;


public class Example {   

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i =0; i<10000;i++){
        try {
            System.out.println(i);
            compile();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public static void compile() throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    File source = new File( "src\\Example.java" ); // This File
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager( null, null, null );
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> units;
    units = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles( Arrays.asList( source ) );
    compiler.getTask( null, fileManager, null, null, null, units ).call();
    fileManager.close();
}

}
```

Comment: I suspect maybe your previous class definitions are being retained in [PermGen space](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation).

Comment: The class definition gets unloaded when I set the classloader to null. and garbage collect. (JConsole tells me) in JConsole I also see the memory usage of PS Perm Gen. it does not take a lot of memory ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first, I thought this was a definite memory leak; however, it is directly related to how `SoftReference`s work.

**Oracle's JVM will only attempt to collect soft references when the heap is completely used up.** It appears that it is not possible to force soft references to be collected programatically.

To identify the problem, I used three dumps on an 'unlimited' heap:

1. Start up the app and get the Compiler and ScriptFileManager, then do a GC-finalize-GC. Make a dump.
2. Load 500 'scripts'.
3. Do a GC-finalize-GC. Write stats. Make a dump.
4. Load 500 'scripts'.
5. Do a GC-finalize-GC. Write stats. Make a dump.

The obvious (double) instance count increase: `Names` (500 -> 1k), `SharedNameTable` (500->1k), `SharedNameTable$NameImpl` (in the hundreds of thousands) and `[LSharedNameTable$NameImpl` (500->1k).

After analyzing with EMA, it becomes apparent that `SharedNameTable` has a static reference to a `com.sun.tools.javac.util.List` which apparently `SoftReference`s every single `SharedNameTable` ever created (so one for each source file you have compiled during runtime). All the `$NameImpl`s are the tokens your source file(s) were split to. And apparently all the tokens are **never** freed from the heap and accumulate to no end... Or do they?

I decided to test if this was actually the case. Knowing the difference of soft vs weak references, I decided to use a small heap (-Xms32m -Xmx32m). This way JVM is forced to either free `SharedNameTable`s or fail with `OutOfMemoryError`. The results speak for themselves:

-Xmx512m -Xms512m

```
Total memory: 477233152
Free memory: 331507232
Used memory: 138.97506713867188 MB
Loaded scripts: 500

Total memory: 489816064
Free memory: 203307408
Used memory: 273.23594665527344 MB
Loaded scripts: 1000

The classloader/component "java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @ 0x8a8a748" occupies 279.709.192 (98,37%) bytes.
```

-Xmx32m -Xms32m

```
Total memory: 29687808
Free memory: 25017112
Used memory: 4.454322814941406 MB
Loaded scripts: 500

Total memory: 29884416
Free memory: 24702728
Used memory: 4.941642761230469 MB
Loaded scripts: 1000

One instance of "com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndex" loaded by "java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @ 0x8aa4cc8" occupies 2.230.736 (47,16%) bytes. The instance is referenced by *.*.script.ScriptFileManager @ 0x8ac8230.
```

(This is merely a link to a JDK library.)

Script:

```
public class Avenger
{
    public Avenger()
    {
        JavaClassScriptCache.doNotCollect(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // this method is called after compiling
        new Avenger();
    }
}
```

doNotCollect:

```
private static final int TO_LOAD = 1000;
private static final List<Object> _active = new ArrayList<Object>(TO_LOAD);

public static void doNotCollect(Object o)
{
    _active.add(o);
}

System.out.println("Loaded scripts: " + _active.size());
```

Comment: Wow great answer, I will check that when I have time !

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I did a similar test with doing the compilation tasks in a loop. I ran this with heap size set to minimal, 64M and I saw that both heap and permgen remained stable. I ran the same program with bigger heap 4G and saw that the heap indeed gets full, but still doesn't cause OOM, it gets cleaned up as necessary and needed. Which proves the soft references theory.

Answer (score 5):

Java 7 introduced this bug: in an attempt to speed up compilation, they introduced the SharedNameTable, which uses soft references to avoid reallocations, but unfortunately just causes the JVM to bloat out of control, as those soft references will **never** be reclaimed until the JVM hits its `-Xmx` memory limit. Allegedly it will be fixed in Java 9. In the meantime, there's an (undocumented) compiler option to disable it: `-XDuseUnsharedTable`.

Comment: This is actually the most correct answer but was missing the details. This is actually a bug and seems that it has been fixed in JSE v8 u60.

The list of fixes in JSE v8 u60:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u60-bugfixes-2620228.html


Link to the original bug for this issue in JSE v9:
http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8039262


Link to the issue for back integration of the fix in JSE v8 u60:
http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8129714

Comment: Thanks @Jawad. Can I suggest you write your own answer with this new information, rather than my editing my old one? I'll upvote it when I see it :)

Comment: Haven't been able to find any time to get to this :( really feel guilty sometimes that StackOverflow has been sooo beneficial to me over the past several years and yet I rarely find the time to contribute.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have already pointed out, the problem is that the compiler keeps `SoftReference`s to `SharedNameTable` around.

Chrispy mentioned the `-XDuseUnsharedTable` javac option. So the last missing bit is how to enable this option when using the Java API:

```
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, Arrays.asList("-XDuseUnsharedTable"), null, units)
```

Answer (score 2):

> The class definition gets unloaded when I set the classloader to null. and garbage collect. JConsole also tells me that those classes are unloaded. Total classes loaded gets back to the initial value.

That's pretty convincing evidence that this is not a classical classloader leak.

> Also eclipse memory analyzer thinks it is a com.sun.tools.javac.util.List Object which takes the memory.... so it is on the heap

The next step should be to identify where the reference (or references) to that List object are.  With a bit of luck, you can then look at the source code to find what the list object is used for, and whether there is some way to cause it to be cleared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes that's what I am trying but it did not succeed. As I said Memory Analyzer says it is a FactoryURLClassLoader:

_The classloader/component "java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @ 0x702e49db8" occupies 252.643.960 (98,20%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "com.sun.tools.javac.util.List" loaded by "java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @ 0x702e49db8"_     .... But since that Class and its ancestors does not declare any com.sun.tools.javac.util.List I dont really know where to look

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting something.  It seems to be saying that the List class was LOADED by the FactoryURLClassLoader.  You need to find what is referencing the List INSTANCES ... not the class.  If you can't make progress yourself, create an SSCCE so that other people can attempt to reproduce this ... and have a look at what is actually going on.

Comment: When I get you right, you mean I dont need the Class name but the Instance, thats true but I dont know how to find it. MemoryAnalyzer does not tell me. I searched inside of the SystemToolClassLoader for instances of com.sun.tools.javac.util.List and didn't find any. But I got the info from the Memory Analyzer that the List seems to be in side of a  com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable Object. So I need to find out what instantiates that kind of object and is saved inside of a FactoryURLClassLoader.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a memory leak, its like "since memory is available and there is something useful to keep, until it is really necessary to get rid of and release memory, I'll keep the compiled source for you". --Compiler says

Basically compiler tool ( the internal compiler tool being used here) keeps references to the source that was compiled, it is though, kept as soft references. Which means that garbage collector will claim the memory retained by it if the JVM will tend to go our of memory.
Try to run your code with minimal heap size, you'll see the references being cleaned up.